# How to check if a Session variable contain null or Not in spring mvc 3 using JSTL tag <c:if >

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl, spring-3

Want to check that session Variable "Sess_Var" contain null or not

```
<c:if test="${Sess_Var=='NULL'}" >
 <%
   response.sendRedirect("doLogin.obj");
  %>
```

But its not working,It doesnt check it

Comment: ${Sess_Var} displays the value but in if null is not checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to check if it is NULL (as opposed to checking if the variable contain the String 'NULL' then you could do

```
<c:if test="${empty Sess_Var}">
```

This checks to see whether the variable is empty or null and evaluates to `true` if it is either.

Comment: Shouldn't your check be reversed - `${empty Sess_Var}`?